# Synonym for 'dial into'

Tags: synonyms

I am doing an online news update for my company and though 3 of us have tried we can't work out a good synonym for the phrase *dial into*.

The sentence reads:-

> Also with the summer holidays looming you may find yourself short staffed, but with the SIP Soft-phone anyone can *dial into* company calls, whether they are at work, at home or even in the Mediterranean soaking up the sun.

We were wondering if there is a better way to say *dial into*, it has to do with making business calls when you are out of the office and you can make or receive them.

It's just a small quandary but if you have any ideas I'll welcome them.

Comment: What do you mean by "dial into"?  Join conference calls?

Comment: Probably ***connect to*** company calls.

Comment: Welcome to ELU :-). There is no need to edit the title to name the question 'solved': you can either [accept an answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) (but it is advised to wait with that for at least a day), or if you got your answer in a comment if you need a better explanation you could ask the person who replied to expand it into a full answer. Please refer to the [help centre](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for more information on asking and answering questions on ELU. You may also like our sister site [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: .......... join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *company calls* refers to *any* calls related to the business of the company, then possible idiomatic phrases would be

**place company calls**

**make company calls**

**receive company calls**

**get company calls**

If *company calls* refers to conference calls already in progress:

**join company calls**

**join in on company calls**

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the term *dial up* with a more modern analogue, such as *access*, *connect*, *log in*, or some similar modern construct. I haven't yet seen a smartphone with a rotary dial and I suspect there are many people who have only ever seen a rotary dial telephone set in a movie, old photo, or in a museum.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it might be wise to use the phrase 'dial-in', but to supplement it with another verb that explicitly states what action is occurring. That should make your sentence read more clearly.

Dialling-in to a call is one of several methods of joining a call - an alternative being a caller dialling-in *to you*, or you joining via a computer, etc. Hence, I think it's necessary to preserve that term because it clarifies the specific mechanism of your system.

You could go with:

> Also, with the summer holidays looming, you may find yourself short staffed, but with the SIP Soft-phone anyone can join company calls by simply 'dialling-in' from their local phone, whether they are at work, at home or even in the Mediterranean soaking up the sun.

Comment: Thanks for revising, however I prefer the British spelling - 'dialling' - and I believe that it is just as valid as that with a single 'l'.